# Is all of put option time value when OTM?

Tags: options, financial-literacy, put-options

If I sell a Dec 65 strike put on 12/3 and on 12/7 the stock price is at $74 and the put bid/ask are .35 x .37, how much of that is time value?

Comment: Think about it. What is the in-the-money value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call is out-of-the-money (OTM) if the strike price  is higher than the market price of the underlying.

A put is out-of-the-money if the strike price  is lower than the market price of the underlying.

If an option is OTM, all of its premium is time premium.

Your put has a strike price below $74 so all of it is time value.